# Bootstrap Formatting Rendering on my_site.com:8000, not on my_site.com

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, bootstrap-4, gunicorn

I have a personal website that leverages Flask, NginX, Gunicorn, and MySQL. It runs perfectly well, however, I am porting it over to a set of Docker containers (mostly to learn Docker).

I am currently facing an issue that I believe stems from my NginX configuration, as I am attempting to forward traffic to my_site to my_site:8000 [code block 1 below].

My problem is this: I finally got the forwarding to work, in that when I go to my_site.com, it renders my HTML (presumably through forwarding to Gunicorn's exposed port 8000). But, it does not format it using the bootstrap4 formatting. My terminal does show a 200 response for finding my main.css file, however. The strange part is that when I go to my_site:8000, it does properly format my pages!

Do any of you have an idea as to what could be my mix up? I've double checked my port exposures, my docker services references, etc. but cannot figure out what the differentiation is in specifying that port 8000, after what I believe was a successful implementation of the proxy_pass to port 8000 in my NginX configuration.

My docker-compose.yml file contents are shown below in code block 2

The NginX container is from the official NginX image on Docker hub

The MySQL container is from the official MariaDB image on Docker hub

The other containers are built upon Ubuntu 18.10 images. I simply downloaded Python, nano, requirements.txt, etc. on these.

Block 1 -- conf.d file for NginX

```py
events { }

http {

    upstream upstream-web {
        server jonathanolson.us;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name gunicornservice;

        location /static {
            alias /NHL-Project/flasksite/static;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://gunicornservice:8000;
            # include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Block 2 -- docker-compose.yml

```py
version: '3.7'
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nhlflasknetwork
services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: jonathanguy/mymariadb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /home/jonathan/NHL-Project
        target: /NHL-Project
      - type: volume
        source: mynhldb
        target: /var/lib/mysql
      - type: volume
        source: myConfig
        target: /etc/mySecrets # Here, we will have the file /etc/mySecrets/config.py
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER_FILE=/etc/mySecrets/mysql_user_file
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE=/etc/mySecrets/mysql_user_password_file
  web:
    restart: always
    image: jonathanguy/myflask
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /home/jonathan/NHL-Project
        target: /NHL-Project
      - type: volume
        source: myConfig
        target: /etc/mySecrets # Here, we will have the file /etc/mySecrets/config.py
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/etc/mySecrets/mysql_root_password_file
      - MYSQL_USER_FILE=/etc/mySecrets/mysql_user_file
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE=/etc/mySecrets/mysql_user_password_file
    depends_on:
      - db # Tells docker that "web" can start once "db" is started and running
    command: bash -c "python3 NHL-Project/flaskrun.py"
  server:
    build: ./myNginx
    depends_on:
      - web
    volumes:
      - type: bind # TODO -- Make this a volume mount for production
        source: /home/jonathan/NHL-Project/flasksite/templates
        target: /usr/share/nginx/html
      - type: bind # TODO -- Make this a volume mount for production
        source: /home/jonathan/NHL-Project/flasksite/static/favicon.ico
        target: /usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico
      - type: bind
        source: /home/jonathan/NHL-Project/conf/conf.d
        target: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    environment:
     - NGINX_PORT=80
    command: /bin/bash -c "chown -R nginx /usr/share/nginx/html && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
  gunicornservice:
    image: jonathanguy/mygunicorn
    depends_on:
      - server
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /home/jonathan/NHL-Project
        target: /NHL-Project
      - type: volume
        source: myConfig
        target: /etc/mySecrets
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /bin/bash -c "gunicorn -w 5 flaskrun:app -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    working_dir: /NHL-Project
volumes:
  mynhldb:
    external: true
  myConfig:
    external: true
  myCode:
    external: true
```

I expect my full site to be rendered and formatted correctly when visiting my_site.com

Given my (successful?) implementation of a proxy_pass in the NginX config, I am getting all the HTML and successful finding of the main.css file.

I still have to visit my_site.com:8000 to have the html formatted using the specified bootstrap formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming form this snippet

`location /static {
       alias /NHL-Project/flasksite/static;
 }`

Your css files are placed hear.
This block is what is I guess is creating the issue as nginx service will try to find the file in its container directory, but this which be served from your web container.
Try removing that block from nginx conf file.
Also, if possible avoid binding volumes of the code where it is not required like nginx and MySQL.